# Complex Analysis and Proper Holomorphic Maps

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove there is no proper holomorphic map from the unit disc into the complex plane.

I know as $z$ approaches the boundary of the unit disc, $f(z)$ will approach infinity, hence unbounded. 
Can we take $F=1/f$ and use the maximum principle to somehow show it is constant?

Comment: Why don’t you do it? See [ask].

Comment: What is proper holomorphic map?

Comment: For any compact set in C, the inverse image of the holomorphic map is compact in D,

Comment: @julien Can you carry this out? Why can’t $f$ be surjective and how can one show that $\frac{1}{f+c}$ attains a maximum?

Comment: @K.Stm. Not sure about what I said yesterday...actually.